# Reading from a file all elements within it in C

Tags: c, file, fread, realloc

So I need to write a function that reads all the elements inside a bit file. The point is that I don't know how many elements there could be inside, but I know what type of elements are. So I tried to write this function:

```
   void loadData(Parallelogram **array) {
            FILE *data; long size;
            //int numberOfElements = 0;
            int numberOfObjects = 0;


            if ((data = fopen(name, "rb"))!=NULL) {


                fseek(data, 0, SEEK_END);
                size = ftell(data);
                fseek(data, 0, SEEK_SET);


                if (size<(long)sizeof(Parallelogram)) {

                    printf("The file is empty try to open another file maybe");

                } else {

                    Parallelogram *tempArray;

                    numberOfObjects = size/sizeof(Parallelogram);

                    tempArray = realloc(*array, numberOfObjects*sizeof(Parallelogram));

                    if (tempArray==NULL) {
                         printf("There was an error reallocating memory");
                    } else { *array = tempArray; }

                    fread(*array, sizeof(Parallelogram), numberOfObjects, data);

                }
            }
            fclose(data);
        }
```

The elements are struct objects of type Parallelogram, storing a few floats.
The commented out part was me trying another method form another question but not understanding the real mechanism. Anyways when I call the function the array is empty. What am I getting wrong?

EDIT: As requested this is the main function where I call the function loadData()

```
int main() {
    Parallelogram *paraArray = NULL;
    loadData(&paraArray);
}
```

Comment: What are these elements? I didn't understand if they have a specified size

Comment: Shouldn't the name of the file or the `FILE *` itself be a parameter of the function? Beside that, the variable `size` should be of type `size_t`.

Comment: @GalAbra thanks for letting me notice... I forgot to mention that the elements are struct type objects. added it to the post too now

Comment: `*array = realloc(*array, ..` may lead to memory leaks if there is no space for the reallocation.

Comment: @ManceRayder the name is defined in the function and scanned from the input, I just cut out the unnecessary parts. Anyways, I tried with size_t but I get the same result

Comment: @ManceRayder and how can I prevent or check if there is space for reallocation?

Comment: @L_Cleo just do `Parallelogram * p = realloc(*array, ...); if (p == NULL) { ...error...} else { *array = p; ... }`. Note the the byte order / types size / alignments / padding must be the same for the program creating the file and the current program

Comment: Also do not forget to _fclose_ (if you open too much files _fopen_ fails)

Comment: It still returns an empty array @bruno

Comment: @L_Cleo can you show the call of _loadData_ including the declaration and initialization of the location you give the address in arg ?

Comment: @L_Cleo to introduce _tempArray_ as you do without testing if it is NULL after _realloc_ is  just useless

Comment: @L_Cleo leave user I/O out of the function. I would use a `FILE *` as an argument, and a variable to save the number of objects read (it may also be a return value).

Comment: @bruno I edited the code and added the check if the pointer is NULL, but I can't figure out why it is giving me an empty array. The error doesn't get printed so tempArray is not NULL.

Comment: @ManceRayder I can try that, but what I/O are you talking about?

Comment: @L_Cleo pity, in case of an error in the _realloc_ you use the old value of `*array` so you don't have the guaranty to have enough memory or may be you have a null pointer (not possible to know while you do not show the call as I proposed you to show), sorry but I'm giving up ...

Comment: @L_Cleo in a previous comment you said "the name is defined in the function and scanned from the input", I would do that in `main()`, including the `fopen()`. `printf()` it's also user I/O (output in that case). @bruno he added the call at the end of the post.

Comment: @ManceRayder will that make any difference? Just curious... Anyways I tried to print out the number of elements within the file and it outputs "8" which is correct. I still don't understand where could be the problem

Comment: @bruno I added it at the end of my post

Comment: Not to your post, it's programming style. You may ignore it. Have you tried my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** complete function more or less like the OP's.

You may do something like:

```
void loadData(Parallelogram **array, size_t * n) {
    FILE *data;

    if ((data = fopen("file.bin", "rb"))!=NULL) {
        Parallelogram buffer[100]; // may be malloc'd
        size_t chunk_size = 100;
        size_t read_size = 0;
        size_t number_of_objects = 0;
        Parallelogram *aux = NULL;
        *array = NULL;

        while ((read_size = fread(buffer, sizeof *buffer, chunk_size, data)) > 0) {
            aux = realloc(*array, (number_of_objects + read_size) * sizeof *buffer);
            if (aux == NULL) {
                // ERROR
                free(*array);
                // clean, break/exit
            }
            *array = aux;
            memcpy(*array + number_of_objects, buffer, read_size*sizeof *buffer);
            number_of_objects += read_size;
        }
        // check file for errors (ferror()) before exit
        fclose(data);
        *n = number_of_objects;
    }
}
```

Comment: Doing `*array = NULL;` you leak the memory may be already pointed by `*array`. For you what in your proposal is better than the OP one ? Note also `sizeof (char)` is 1 by definition, it is useless to do `sizeof *buffer`. Your `memcpy(*array + number_of_objects, aux, read_size);` is wrong, you need to copy from _buffer_ rather than from _aux_ being `*array`

Comment: @bruno I assume the array is not pointing anywhere useful, if it is, the OP using `realloc(*array...` AND `numberOfObjects = 0` has no sense. And buffer is a Parallelogram array, not a char array.

Comment: You cannot asume that. You do several reads, several calls of _realloc_, several (wrong) copy ... without solving anything in the OP code

Comment: @bruno I think the OP starts with "So I need to write a function that reads all the elements inside a bit file." my answer, presumably, is doing that. If there's a safe and standard way to get the file size, putting that value in chunk_size (in structs size) will do 1 read and 1 alloc, right? By the way, thanks for pointing the error in `memcpy()`, honest mistake.

Comment: @ManceRayder I tried this one out too. I'm starting to think that I'll never get out of it

Comment: @L_Cleo I missed a `sizeof` in `memcpy()`, now it works. Try it. By the way, you have to include `string.h`.

Comment: @L_Cleo I've added the rest of the function to complete it (because I don't know what you've tested and which are your errors). I've added a parameter to the function (to return the number of structures in the array).

Comment: Actually it worked even before you posted the full function it's just I didn't modify the global parameter that kept track of the length of the array so when I printed the array he would print 0 Items because the global length value was still 0... But thanks a lot for your help. @ManceRayder