# Parse CSV into dynamically allocated array of structures (ANSI 89)

Tags: c, arrays, csv, segmentation-fault, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying to parse a csv into a dynamically allocated array of structures, however my attempt crashes with a segmentation fault.

Here is the structure of my data:

```
SO02773202,5087001,0
SO02773203,5087001,0
SO02773204,5087001,0
SO02773205,5087001,0
SO02773206,5087001,14
```

This is the struct I am parsing the data into:

```
typedef struct saleslines{
  char* salesid;
  char* smmcampaignid;
  int numberofbottles;
} saleslines_t;
```

Here is my attempt at parsing the file:

```
int read_saleslines(saleslines_t* saleslines, int number_of_lines){
  char c;

  FILE* fp; 
  fp = fopen(FILENAME, "r");             /* Open the saleslines file */

  if(fp == NULL){                              /* Crash if file not found */
  printf("Error - file not found\n");
    return 0;
  }

  c = getc(fp);
  while (c != EOF){
    if (c == '\n'){
    number_of_lines += 1;
    }
    c = getc(fp);
  }

  printf("Number of lines is %d\n", number_of_lines);

  saleslines = (saleslines_t*) malloc((number_of_lines * 2) * sizeof(saleslines_t));

  /* allocation of the buffer for every line in the File */
  char *buf = (char*) malloc(1000);
  char *tmp; 

  if ( ( fp = fopen(FILENAME, "r" ) ) == NULL )
  {
    printf( "File could not be opened.\n" );
  }
  int i = 0;
  while (fgets(buf, 255, fp) != NULL){
    if ((strlen(buf)>0) && (buf[strlen (buf) - 1] == '\n'))
      buf[strlen (buf) - 1] = '\0';       

    tmp = strtok(buf, ",");
    saleslines[i].salesid = strdup(tmp);

    tmp = strtok(NULL, ",");
    saleslines[i].smmcampaignid = strdup(tmp);

    tmp = strtok(NULL, ",");
    saleslines[i].numberofbottles = atoi(tmp);

    printf("Salesid: %s\nCampaign: %s\nBottles: %i\n\n", saleslines[i].salesid , saleslines[i].smmcampaignid, saleslines[i].numberofbottles);

    i++;
  }
  free(buf);
  fclose(fp);
  printf("Number of lines is %i\n", number_of_lines);
  return number_of_lines;
}
```

For some reason it parses the file and prints the resulting array of structs, however when I call this function immediately after, it crashes with a segfault:

```
void print_saleslines_struct(saleslines_t* saleslines, int number_of_lines{
  int i;
  printf("Number of lines is %i", number_of_lines);
  for(i = 0; i < number_of_lines; i++){
    printf("Salesid:\t %s\n", saleslines[i].salesid);
    printf("Campaign:\t %s\n", saleslines[i].smmcampaignid);
    printf("# of Bottles:\t %d\n", saleslines[i].numberofbottles);
  }
}
```

I can't seem to find where this memory bug is.

Here is the initialization and main:

```
saleslines_t* saleslines;
saleslines_summary_t* saleslines_summary;
saleslines_grouped_t* saleslines_grouped;
int number_of_lines = 0;
int* number_of_linesp = &number_of_lines;

/* Main */

int main(){

  int chosen_option;

  while(1){

    printf("What would you like to do?\n");
    printf("1. Read saleslines.txt\n");
    printf("2. Print saleslines\n");
    printf("3. Summarise saleslines\n");
    printf("4. Exit the program\n");

    scanf("%d", &chosen_option);

    switch(chosen_option){

    /*  case 1 : number_of_lines = read_saleslines_file(saleslines, number_of_lines); break; */

      case 1 : number_of_lines = read_saleslines(saleslines, number_of_lines); break;

      case 2 : printf("Number of lines is %i", number_of_lines);  print_saleslines_struct(saleslines, number_of_lines); break;

      case 3 : summarise_saleslines(saleslines, number_of_linesp, saleslines_summary, saleslines_grouped); break;

      case 4 : free(saleslines); free(saleslines_summary); free(saleslines_grouped); return 0;   

    }

  }

  return 0;

}
```

*Update*

The issue seems to be with my initialization of the array of structures.

When I initialize it like this: `saleslines_t* saleslines;`
and then malloc like this: `saleslines = malloc(number_of_lines + 1 * sizeof(saleslines_t);`

I get a segfault.

But if I initialize like this: `saleslines[600];` (allocating more than the number of lines in the file), everything works.

How can I get around this? I would like to be able to dynamically allocate the number of entries within the struct array.

*Edit 2*

Here are the changes as suggested:

```
int read_saleslines(saleslines_t** saleslines, int number_of_lines);

saleslines_t* saleslines;
int number_of_lines = 0;

int main(){

  while(1){

    printf("What would you like to do?\n");
    printf("1. Read saleslines.txt\n");
    printf("2. Print saleslines\n");
    printf("3. Summarise saleslines\n");
    printf("4. Exit the program\n");

    printf("Number of saleslines = %i\n", number_of_lines);

    scanf("%d", &chosen_option);

    switch(chosen_option){

    /*  case 1 : number_of_lines = read_saleslines_file(saleslines, number_of_lines); break; */

      case 1 : number_of_lines = read_saleslines(&saleslines, number_of_lines); break;

      case 2 : printf("Number of lines is %i", number_of_lines);  print_saleslines_struct(saleslines, number_of_lines); break;

      case 3 : summarise_saleslines(saleslines, number_of_linesp, saleslines_summary, saleslines_grouped); break;

      case 4 : free(saleslines); free(saleslines_summary); free(saleslines_grouped); return 0;   

    }

  }

  return 0;

}

int read_saleslines(saleslines_t** saleslines, int number_of_lines)
{

  char c;

  FILE* fp; 
  fp = fopen(FILENAME, "r");             /* Open the saleslines file */

  if(fp == NULL){                              /* Crash if file not found */
  printf("Error - file not found\n");
    return 0;
  }

  c = getc(fp);
  while (c != EOF){
    if (c == '\n'){
    number_of_lines += 1;
    }
    c = getc(fp);
  }

  fclose(fp);

  printf("Number of lines is %d\n", number_of_lines);

  *saleslines = (saleslines_t*) malloc((number_of_lines + 1) * sizeof(saleslines_t));

  /* allocation of the buffer for every line in the File */
  char *buf = malloc(25);
  char *tmp; 

  if ( ( fp = fopen(FILENAME, "r" ) ) == NULL )
  {
    printf( "File could not be opened.\n" );
  }
  int i = 0;
  while (fgets(buf, 25, fp) != NULL){
    if ((strlen(buf)>0) && (buf[strlen (buf) - 1] == '\n'))
      buf[strlen (buf) - 1] = '\0';       

    tmp = strtok(buf, ",");
    (*saleslines)[i].salesid = strdup(tmp);

    tmp = strtok(NULL, ",");
    (*saleslines)[i].smmcampaignid = strdup(tmp);

    tmp = strtok(NULL, ",");
    (*saleslines)[i].numberofbottles = atoi(tmp);

    printf("Salesid: %s\nCampaign: %s\nBottles: %i\n\n", saleslines[i]->salesid , saleslines[i]->smmcampaignid, saleslines[i]->numberofbottles);

    i++;
  }
  free(buf);
  fclose(fp);
  printf("Number of lines is %i\n", number_of_lines);
  return number_of_lines;
}
```

The program now segfaults after reading the first element in the struct array.

Comment: What is this?? `saleslines[i].numberofbottles = (int) malloc(sizeof(int));` Also see: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Comment: That was me trying everything possible to eliminate a memory bug - behaviour is the same when you remove it. Infact here, ill edit it out for you.

Comment: Chuckling.... OK, **Rule No. 1**, you no longer *"Change X, Recompile, See if it works, Repeat, ..."* That's guessing, not programming `:)` Give me a second and I'll go though the rest.

Comment: In your edit, I think you missed some parenthesis. Why are you calling `malloc(1000)` for `buf` if then you use `fgets()` with `255`? You can get rid of those unnecessary global variables. Please, please, bare in mind that disk access is the slowest thing you can do (without accessing internet), so reading the file **twice** must be avoided in your code; you can `realloc` the array while reading the file. I've answered a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56741018/9987237) a few days ago.

Comment: I think you should reduce the code you've written for the question, it must be a **minimal** example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem with the arguments of `read_saleslines()`. The first argument should be a pointer to an array of your structs, meaning a double pointer.

In

```
int read_saleslines(saleslines_t* saleslines, int number_of_lines){
```

you want to modify where `saleslines` is pointing. `saleslines` is a local variable of the function, and the scope is that function. Once you exit `read_saleslines()`, the variable is "destroyed", meaning that the value it holds it is not accessible anymore. Adding another level of indirection, a pointer, you can modify the variable that's defined **outside** the function, being that (ugly) global or other. So, change that argument so that the function prototype matches

```
int read_saleslines(saleslines_t** saleslines, int *);
```

and change the places where you access it **inside** the function (adding an `*` to access it, for example:

```
saleslines = (saleslines_t*) malloc((number_of_lines * ...
```

to

```
*saleslines = (saleslines_t*) malloc((number_of_lines * ...
```

and

```
saleslines[i].salesid = strdup(tmp);
```

to

```
(*saleslines)[i].salesid = strdup(tmp);
```

Then add an `&` where you use the variable outside the function:

```
number_of_lines = read_saleslines(saleslines, number_of_lines);
```

changes to

```
some_var = read_saleslines(&saleslines, &number_of_lines);
```

That will make you code work.

Comment: Thank you for this - I have updated with suggested changes except for the &number_of_lines as I am passing the correct value. Edits in the original question - the program now segfaults after the first struct in the array is read and printed.

Comment: Have you changed the use of `saleslines` inside the function or just the prototype?

Comment: I have changed it inside the function also - the updated function is included in the updated code above

Comment: The change you've made to `printf`'s arguments is wrong. You've added `->`, but the array is still an array of structs, not pointers, i.e., `(*saleslines)[i]` is the struct. `saleslines[i]->` is equivalent to `*saleslines[i]`, which is the same as `*(saleslines[i])`, and `saleslines[i]` is not a pointer, is a struct.

Answer (score 1):

You have a large number of errors in your code, and with your approach in general. There is no need to make two-passes over the file to determine the number of lines before allocating and then re-reading the file in an attempt to parse the data. Further, there is no need to tokenize each line to separate the comma-separated-values, `sscanf()` to parse the two strings and one `int` is sufficient here after reading each line with `fgets`.

While you are free to pass any mix of parameters you like and return whatever you like, since you are allocating for an array of struct and reading values into the array, it makes sense to return a pointer to the allocated array from your function (or `NULL` on failure) and simply update a parameter passed as a pointer to make the total number of lines read available back in the caller.

Further, generally you want to open and validate the file in the caller and pass a `FILE*` parameter passing the open file stream to your function. With that in mind, you could refactor your function as:

```
/* read saleslines into array of saleslines_t, allocating for
 * salesid, and smmcampaignid within each struct. Return pointer
 * to allocated array on success with lines updated to hold the
 * number of elements, or NULL otherwise.
 */
saleslines_t *read_saleslines (FILE *fp, size_t *lines)
{
```

Within your function, you simply need a buffer to hold each line read, a counter to track the number of elements allocated in your array, and a pointer to your array to return. For example, you could do something like the following to handle all three:

```
    char buf[MAXC];                 /* buffer to hold line */
    size_t maxlines = MINL;         /* maxlines allocated */
    saleslines_t *sales = NULL;     /* pointer to array of struct */
```

(**note:** since you are tracking the number of lines read through the pointer `lines` passed as a parameter, it would make sense to initialize the value at that address to zero)

Now the work of your function begins, you want to read each line into `buf` and parse the needed information from each line. Since `salesid` and `smmcampaignid` are both pointers-to-char in your struct, you will need to allocate a block of memory for each string parsed from the line, copy the string to the new block of memory, and then assign the beginning address for the bock to each of your pointers. To "dynamically" handle allocating elements for your struct, you simply check if the number of lines (`*lines`) filled equals against the number allocated (`maxlines`), (or if `*lines` is zero indicating a need for an initial allocation), and `realloc` in both cases to either `realloc` (or newly allocate) storage for your array of struct.

When you `realloc` you always `realloc` using a *temporary* pointer so if `realloc` fails and returns `NULL`, you don't overwrite your pointer to the currently allocated block with `NULL` thereby creating a memory leak.

Putting all that together at the beginning of your function may seem daunting, but it is actually straight forward, e.g.

```
    while (fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) { /* read each line in file */
        char id[MAXC], cid[MAXC];   /* temp arrays to hold strings */
        int bottles;                /* temp int for numberofbottles */
        if (*lines == maxlines || !*lines) {    /* check if realloc req'd */
            /* always realloc with a temp pointer */
            void *tmp = realloc (sales, 2 * maxlines * sizeof *sales);
            if (!tmp) { /* if realloc fails, original pointer still valid */
                perror ("realloc-sales");   /* throw error */
                return sales;               /* return current pointer      */ 
            }                               /* (don't exit or return NULL) */
            sales = tmp;    /* assign reallocated block to sales */
            /* (optional) zero newly allocated memory */
            memset (sales + *lines, 0, maxlines * sizeof *sales);
            maxlines *= 2;  /* update maxlines allocated */
        }
```

Now you are ready to parse the wanted information from your line with `sscanf`, and then following a successful parse of information, you can allocate for each of your `salesid` and `smmcampaignid` pointers, copy the parsed information to the new blocks of memory assigning the beginning address to each pointer, respectively, e.g.

```
        /* parse needed data from line (sscanf is fine here) */
        if (sscanf (buf, "%1023[^,],%1023[^,],%d", id, cid, &bottles) == 3) {
            size_t  idlen  = strlen (id),   /* get lengths of strings */
                    cidlen = strlen (cid);
            sales[*lines].salesid = malloc (idlen + 1); /* allocate string */
            if (!sales[*lines].salesid) {               /* validate! */
                perror ("malloc-sales[*lines].salesid");
                break;
            }
            sales[*lines].smmcampaignid = malloc (cidlen + 1);  /* ditto */
            if (!sales[*lines].smmcampaignid) {
                perror ("malloc-sales[*lines].smmcampaignid");
                break;
            }
            memcpy (sales[*lines].salesid, id, idlen + 1);  /* copy strings */
            memcpy (sales[*lines].smmcampaignid, cid, cidlen + 1);
            sales[(*lines)++].numberofbottles = bottles;    /* assign int */
        }   /* (note lines counter updated in last assignment) */
```

(**note:** you can use `strdup` to both get the length of each string parsed and allocate sufficient memory to hold the string and assign that to your pointer in one-shot, e.g. `sales[*lines].salesid = strdup (id);`, but... `strdup` is not required to be included in C99 or later, so it is just as simple to get the length, allocate `length + 1` bytes and then `memcpy` your string manually to ensure portability. Further, since `strdup` allocates memory, you must **validate** the pointer returned -- something overlooked by 99% of those using it.)

That's it, when `fgets()` fails, you have reached `EOF`, now simply:

```
    return sales;   /* return dynamically allocated array of struct */
}
```

Putting it altogether in a short, working example that takes the filename to read as the first argument to your program (or reads from `stdin` by default if no argument is given), you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC 1024   /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define MINL    2

typedef struct saleslines{
    char *salesid;
    char *smmcampaignid;
    int numberofbottles;
} saleslines_t;

/* read saleslines into array of saleslines_t, allocating for
 * salesid, and smmcampaignid within each struct. Return pointer
 * to allocated array on success with lines updated to hold the
 * number of elements, or NULL otherwise.
 */
saleslines_t *read_saleslines (FILE *fp, size_t *lines)
{
    char buf[MAXC];                 /* buffer to hold line */
    size_t maxlines = MINL;         /* maxlines allocated */
    saleslines_t *sales = NULL;     /* pointer to array of struct */

    *lines = 0;     /* zero lines */

    while (fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) { /* read each line in file */
        char id[MAXC], cid[MAXC];   /* temp arrays to hold strings */
        int bottles;                /* temp int for numberofbottles */
        if (*lines == maxlines || !*lines) {    /* check if realloc req'd */
            /* always realloc with a temp pointer */
            void *tmp = realloc (sales, 2 * maxlines * sizeof *sales);
            if (!tmp) { /* if realloc fails, original pointer still valid */
                perror ("realloc-sales");   /* throw error */
                return sales;               /* return current pointer      */ 
            }                               /* (don't exit or return NULL) */
            sales = tmp;    /* assign reallocated block to sales */
            /* (optional) zero newly allocated memory */
            memset (sales + *lines, 0, maxlines * sizeof *sales);
            maxlines *= 2;  /* update maxlines allocated */
        }
        /* parse needed data from line (sscanf is fine here) */
        if (sscanf (buf, "%1023[^,],%1023[^,],%d", id, cid, &bottles) == 3) {
            size_t  idlen  = strlen (id),   /* get lengths of strings */
                    cidlen = strlen (cid);
            sales[*lines].salesid = malloc (idlen + 1); /* allocate string */
            if (!sales[*lines].salesid) {               /* validate! */
                perror ("malloc-sales[*lines].salesid");
                break;
            }
            sales[*lines].smmcampaignid = malloc (cidlen + 1);  /* ditto */
            if (!sales[*lines].smmcampaignid) {
                perror ("malloc-sales[*lines].smmcampaignid");
                break;
            }
            memcpy (sales[*lines].salesid, id, idlen + 1);  /* copy strings */
            memcpy (sales[*lines].smmcampaignid, cid, cidlen + 1);
            sales[(*lines)++].numberofbottles = bottles;    /* assign int */
        }   /* (note lines counter updated in last assignment) */
    }

    return sales;   /* return dynamically allocated array of struct */
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    saleslines_t *sales = NULL; /* pointer to saleslines_t */
    size_t nlines;
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }

    sales = read_saleslines (fp, &nlines);  /* read saleslines */

    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);   /* close file if not stdin */

    for (size_t i = 0; i < nlines; i++) {   /* loop over each */
        printf ("sales[%2zu]:  %s  %s  %2d\n", i, sales[i].salesid,
                sales[i].smmcampaignid, sales[i].numberofbottles);
        free (sales[i].salesid);        /* free salesid */
        free (sales[i].smmcampaignid);  /* free smmcampaignid */
    }
    free (sales);   /* free sales */

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/saleslines dat/saleslines.txt
sales[ 0]:  SO02773202  5087001   0
sales[ 1]:  SO02773203  5087001   0
sales[ 2]:  SO02773204  5087001   0
sales[ 3]:  SO02773205  5087001   0
sales[ 4]:  SO02773206  5087001  14
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to insure you do not attempt to access memory or write beyond/outside the bounds of your allocated block, attempt to read or base a conditional jump on an uninitialized value, and finally, to confirm that you free all the memory you have allocated.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/saleslines dat/saleslines.txt
==19819== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==19819== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==19819== Using Valgrind-3.12.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==19819== Command: ./bin/saleslines dat/saleslines.txt
==19819==
sales[ 0]:  SO02773202  5087001   0
sales[ 1]:  SO02773203  5087001   0
sales[ 2]:  SO02773204  5087001   0
sales[ 3]:  SO02773205  5087001   0
sales[ 4]:  SO02773206  5087001  14
==19819==
==19819== HEAP SUMMARY:
==19819==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==19819==   total heap usage: 13 allocs, 13 frees, 935 bytes allocated
==19819==
==19819== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==19819==
==19819== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==19819== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.

There is nothing difficult in dynamically allocating for anything. Just take it in small enough pieces that you dot all `"I's"` and cross all `"T's"` for each pointer requiring allocation. Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: This is a great answer - I will learn a lot from following your practices so I am doubly appreciative that you went to the effort to explain these concepts as well as provide a working solution. I have chosen to go with the answer from Mance Rayder as (for my purposes in this specific context) it is the approach that involves the least re-writing of the original program; it slots right into the original code with only a change to the way my structures and elements are referenced. Thank you again and I look forward to learning this approach in the future.